# How to test own mongodb wrapper

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mongodb, mocha.js

I have written own thin mongodb wrapper for Node.js to eliminate code repetition.

However, I am having problems with asynchronous unit tests run with Mocha and Should.

What happens is that any thrown exception by Should library is being caught by MongoDB driver instead of Mocha.
I.e., neither Mocha catches the error, nor done() function gets called. As a consequence, Mocha prints out an error `Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded`.

Snippet of wrapper module `db.js`

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

exports.getCollection = function(name, callback) {
    mongodb.connect(dbConfig.dbURI, {auto_reconnect: true}, function(err, db) {
        if (err)
            return callback(err, null);

        db.collection(name, {strict: true}, callback);
    });
};
```

Mocha `test.js`

```
var should = require('should');
var db     = require('./db.js');

describe('Collections', function() {
    it.only('should retrieve user collection', function(done) {
        db.getCollection('user', function(err, coll) {
            should.not.exist(err);
            coll.should.be.a('object');
            // HERE goes an assertion ERROR
            coll.collectionName.should.equal('user123');

            done();
        });
    });
});
```

The same behaviour can be simulated by this simple `test.js`

```
var should = require('should');

var obj = {
    call: function(callback) {
        try {
            console.log('Running callback(null);');
            return callback(null);
        }
        catch(e) {
            console.log('Catched an error:', e);
        }
    }
};

describe('Test', function() {
    it('should catch an error', function(done) {
        obj.call(function(err) {
            should.exist(err);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Is there any way to workaround the issue? There must be a way to test such code.

Comment: Isn't there really no one with an idea? I tried to analyse the problem several times but did not come into any solution. This means I cannot test my DB code at all :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by an accidental luck I spotted [a GitHub fork](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/pull/278) dealing with a different problem, but the code lead me to realise I can use a simple trick to make Mocha to catch the assert exceptions:

```
describe('Test', function() {
    it('should catch an error', function(done) {
        obj.call(function(err) {
            try {
                should.exist(err);
                done();
            } catch (err) {
                done(err);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I.e. wrapping the `should` calls into `try/catch` block and calling `done(err)` in the catch section does exactly what is expected :

1. Test passes successfully if no assertion error occurs
2. Test fails in case of assertion error thanks to `done()` function accepting an error argument